# Divide a face following an existing edge (not part of the face)

Tags: modeling, faces

This is a basic beginner question which should have already an answer, but I don't know what to search for.

I have a mesh with an edge connected to two vertices of a face, but not part of the face:

[image]

I would like to know how the face and the edge can be converted into two quads:

[image]

I know that deleting the face and creating two new ones is possible, but I'm interested in a method not requiring to delete anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an edge there by selecting the two vertices of this provisional edge, and pressing the shortcut key <kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

This nice tool works well even for creating several continuous edges

Comment: @mins, did you create it with the "F" key ("Make Edge/Face")? If so, that edge is unrelated to this face and you can delete it (X > edges). The method specified above will actually split the face and the new edge will be the border edge between the two new faces.

Comment: I don't remember, but likely yes, I'm learning modeling and don't master the different ways of creating elements. I realize that your method is good anyway (deleting the edge, re- creating with Join). Is there a possibility to unify the edge and the face directly?

Comment: If you create an edge with the F key and then with the J key, you'll end up with two edges, one on top of the the other. You can either delete the useless one created with the F key, or use the cleanup operator of the 3D printing toolbox to clean all such overlapping edges. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox